# What is the word for this military term, more specific than "envoy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, military

"Envoy" apparently means messenger or representative, but the military term I want needs to be more specific.

I'm thinking of a group, or just one person, **who goes out before battle, meets the enemy, and asks for surrender or other terms.** This person or group is supposed to be unarmed.

I could have sword such a specific term existed, and it was on the tip of my tongue when I blurted out entourage and envoy, but they weren't what I wanted. It might be a hyphenated thing like "peace-envoy" or something.

Is there a word for what I'm thinking of? Or does "Envoy" specifically mean what I want it to in a military context?

Comment: That's a *red shirt*.

Comment: @jxh lol maybe these days, but in old days they had no radio and had to negotiate prisoner exchanges the old fashioned way.

Comment: More seriously, I am surprised no one has offered *ambassador* or *diplomat*.

Comment: @jxh Because I asked for a very specific meaning, which those two words don't supply since they're too general.

Comment: I suppose, but that's who it is. I don't think you will do much better than the wording in the Hague conventions, though.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably thinking ***emissary***.

> [**emissary**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/emissary) -
>   a representative sent on a mission or errand

Answer (score 2):

*Envoy* can mean exactly what you want: it would be appropriate in the context you describe (although, as you say, it can also be used for a messenger or representative outside a military context). You will see plenty of [examples in Google Books](https://www.google.nl/search?sclient=psy-ab&safe=off&hl=en&biw=1650&bih=897&noj=1&tbm=bks&q=envoy%20truce&oq=envoy%20truce&gs_l=serp.3...10091.10727.1.11164.5.5.0.0.0.0.89.356.5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..5.0.0.vunOmyre86E).

> Under the Hague Regulations, a person is considered an **envoy** bearing a flag of truce (French original: “parlementaire”) if (a) he has been authorized by one of the belligerents to enter into communication with the other; and (b) he advances carrying a white flag.
>
> — [Use of Force · War and Neutrality Peace Treaties (A-M)](https://books.google.com/books?id=UTW0BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=Under+the+Hague+Regulations,+a+person+is+considered+an+envoy+bearing+a+flag+of+truce+%28French+original:+%E2%80%9Cparlementaire%E2%80%9D%29+if+%28a%29+he+has+been+authorized+by+one+of+the+belligerents+to+enter+into+communication+with+the+other;+and+%28b%29+he+advances+...&source=bl&ots=dCyYa2IQsK&sig=XNh0yDAXwNNfCtFYpTGAoDOVIM0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAGoVChMIlYHc46CvxwIVCHEUCh0J0QeY) – Rudolf Bernhardt (2014)

(Perhaps you were thinking of the noun *parley*, or the verb, which, while not describing a person, refer to the exact situation you laid out.)

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't explicitly state he must be unarmed.

Comment: @DrZ214: Indeed. Perhaps because it is difficult to ascertain in advance that he does not carry a concealed weapon?

Answer (score 2):

In Classical and Medieval times this was the **Heralds'** job.

Modern Heralds in U.K. have ceremonial duties.
 http://www.college-of-arms.gov.uk/about-us/heralds-officers

> HERALD   noun ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herald))
>
> 1 a :  an official at a tournament of arms
>   with duties including the making of announcements and the marshaling
>   of combatants
>   b :  an officer with the status of ambassador acting as
>   official messenger between leaders especially in war
>   c (1) :  officer
>   of arms (2) :  an officer of arms ranking above a pursuivant and below
>   a king of arms